# Recover user after sysprep

Tags: windows-7, windows

After i had done a sysprep, my windows is booting a new user inside my old user:
[image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk2uf.jpg)
My original user is the "Fabricio", but windows boots from the empty "fabricio.fabicio-pc" and on the user select screen there's only on fabricio.

My original user has all it's files intact.

Comment: So what is your quesiton exactly?  You will want to delete your user account, then delete the user profile directory, with the built-in Administrator.  You would then use the built-in Administrator account to actually SysPrep the machine

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating it. I want to recover my old user with all my settings.

Comment: If you wanted to do that, why exactly, did you run the one procedure that makes that not possible?

Comment: But my old user with all it's files are in there. Can i not get them back?

Comment: Sure; Create a new user, take ownership of all files in old user's profile directory, and place files in new user's directory

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a few test cases and I was able to "take over" another user's profile directory by [following the tutorial located here](https://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/28/how-to-change-a-windows-account-name-and-user-profile-folder-name/). I did this in a VM but couldn't exactly emulate your scenario. I would recommend you back up anything you care about before trying this.

In essence, the steps are:

1. Create a separate temporary admin account (or re-enable and log on to local admin)
2. Rename the secondary user over to what you want (Fabricio)
3. Edit the Registry to point the user **ProfileImagePath** over to the old user's folder

In more detail you could:

1. [Re-enable](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) and set a password for the default admin account:

   > net user administrator /active:yes
   >   net user administrator mypassword
2. Log on to the new administrator account and rename your old account from
   **Control Panel** > **User Accounts** > **Manage User Accounts**
3. Rename the new account over to the old one in the same control panel
4. Open up the registry. Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> & type **regedit**
5. Navigate to:

   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
6. Search through the folders for the one from your new account (Fabricio.machinename) and then change the key for **ProfileImagePath** to point to your old user (Fabricio) (C:/Users/Fabricio)
   [image: Image from Tutorial]
7. Log back on to the user and verify

Comment: I did that, and maybe did something wrong. Now both users are clean. My files are still here, as my old user' setting i backed up before this. Please can i still recover my settings and everything?

Comment: May be an access issue to some of the files. As Ramhound recommended above, take ownership of all the files in the directory underneath your old user.